# HTML syntax errors highlight with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building chrome extension for 3rd party website that is used by our content team.

I need syntax highlight that will show **SYNTAX ERRORS** - e.g. broken html tags like `< /span>`, broken attributes like `href="http : //domain / page /"`, not properly eclosed tags. is it possible with javascript?

as of now I'm using `highlight.js` with few regex replacements after its job done. any better solutions for this? how do I find missing enclosing tags?

```
$('.edit-definition').each(function (i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML
                .replace(/(&lt;\/\s)/g, "<span class='hljs-red'>$1</span>") //spaces in the start of tag
                .replace(/(\s+>|\s+&gt;)/g, "<span class='hljs-red'>$1</span>") //spaces in the end of tag
                .replace(/(http\s|https\s|\s+\/\/\s+|\s+\\\\\s+|\s+\/\s+|\s+\\\s+)/g, "<span class='hljs-red'>$1</span>") //spaces in urls
        });
```

Comment: why downvoting? I'm searching since yesterday and not able to find anything mentioning ERRORS highlighting

Comment: Likely because it is off topic at SO: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Comment: What IDE are you using ? I think most of IDE now have plugins or already have built in highlight broken html tag ?

Comment: @DarknessZX I need javascript solution to create chrome extension for 3rd party website

Comment: @mplugjan okay now I'm asking not for library but for solution, as of me its the same thing, just slightly rhetorically different -- all similar questions often have libraries as answers

Comment: Parsing HTML in this way is too broad for a SO answer; it'd require a library, so essentially this question is asking for a library recommendation

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of linters available, for example [html-lint](https://github.com/kangax/html-lint).
They will give you all the errors of your **html**.

Note that leading and trailing spaces in the `href` attribute are [allowed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/are-spaces-in-href-valid). The linters most likely won't find spaces inside an URI, these you have to find on your own I using regex.

Comment: as far as I understand I can use linter only to add some note e.g. `this html has 4 errors: ...` but not for syntax highlight?

Comment: This is just an example of course, there are other linters available as well that give you more information and you could collect these errors and then highlight them your own. For example if you look at the source code of this linter, there are all the function needed to check them yourself. Instead of returning a string you could add the error to a map, use the map after linting to highlight your code. I don't know of any library that does all this for you.
Edit: You have to highlight them yourself if you go with this linter, and modify the linter as well.